# Matching URLs with a trailing slash in Rails' routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

Is there a way to perform different routing in Rails' routes.rb depending on whether the request URL has a trailing slash? This seems difficult since the request object has its trailing slash removed, meaning a GET of http://www.example.com/about/ has a request.url value of http://www.example.com/about. That behavior prevents matching using [request-based constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints) as well as [route-globbing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I've found is to use request.env["REQUEST_URI"], which contains the raw URL submitted with the request. Unfortunately, since it's not a direct string property of the request, it requires a [custom matching object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints):

```
class TrailingSlashMatcher
  def matches?(request)
    uri = request.env["REQUEST_URI"]
    !!uri && uri.end_with?("/")
  end
end

AppName::Application.routes.draw do
  match '/example/*path', constraints: TrailingSlashMatcher.new, to: redirect("/somewhere/")
end
```

That seems like overkill, so hopefully someone has a more elegant approach.